# Issue Passing Credentials from ASP.NET To SQL Server

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, iis-7

**Setup:**

IIS on Windows 2008 Server R2 Enterprise, SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, ASP.NET 2.0 Web Application.

**Purpose:**

We are converting the security model of an old web app from using a single SQL Server account to using Active Directory accounts. In the ASP.NET application, we've added `<identity impersonate="true" />` as the first item in the `<system.web>` section of web.config. We've added database roles, which contain Active Directory groups, for granting access to the existing stored procedures. Our web.config already contains `<authentication mode="Windows"/>`. Here is my connection string, editing out server and DB names:

```
<add name="DbConn" 
     connectionString="
         Data Source=SERVER;
         Initial Catalog=DBNAME;
         Integrated Security=SSPI;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
```

**Problem:**

I am getting an error when trying to open an SqlConnection to the database:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Instead of going through all the logical layers of the application (web page to .DLL layers), I threw in a quick, plain web page that does some `Response.Write` in `Page_Load()`. I get this (account info edited out):

> HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name = domain\my account
>
> My.User.Name = domain\my account

Then `Page_Load` calls a Sub that does some `Response.Write` and tries to run an existing stored procedure. I get this:

> Before opening the DB connection ...
>
> HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name = domain\my account
>
> My.User.Name = domain\my account
>
> Sub TestDbCall() Failed! ex.Message = Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

It fails on opening the SqlConnection with error message above (Login failed ...). Clearly, the ASP.NET application recognizes my domain account. It seems that my Windows credentials are not propagating from the ASP.NET app to SQL Server. I'm at a loss as to why.

**EDIT:**

I found this [page on microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) that says in order to access an SQL Server that is not on the IIS server (who would even DO this???), you can't use Windows Authentication in IIS. Rather, you have to use Basic Authentication. It works, but I don't like the idea of users' account name and password floating around the corporate network in plain text. So even though it "works", I don't accept my own finding as an answer.

Comment: Silly question: Does your connection string have "Trusted Connection=true"?

Comment: there might be something in your iis settings. I can't remember what to change but I think you have to change the application pool setting to *not* use the .net service account.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: `Integrated Security=SSPI;` is equivalent to Trusted Connection.

Comment: @HardCode Right; just wanted to check the obvious first.  What authentication methods does the website (in IIS) allow?

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: It **was** Windows Authentication. Then, I found this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z%28v=VS.80%29.aspx. I set authentication to Basic and lo and behold, it worked! However, I don't like the idea of the login box popup and users' windows name and password going over the wire in plain text. I won't accept my discovery as an answer even though it "works".

Comment: @HardCode try changing that to Digest authentication and see if that works.

Comment: +1 for digest , also creds in basic auth can be sent using https

Comment: No, Digest doesn't even allow the web app to run. The login popup appears, but it doesn't accept my account information: 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your IIS authenticates the user using Windows Authentication and then, while impersonating the connected user, it connects to *any* resource outside the local IIS box (like a SQL Server instance) the process is called Delegation, as described in [Kerberos Protocol Transition and Constrained Delegation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739587%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). The process, sometimes referred to informally as 'double hop', is subject of many How-Tos:

- [How To: Use Impersonation and Delegation in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647404.aspx)
- [How to configure an ASP.NET application for a delegation scenario](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810572)
- [Configuring Servers for Delegation (IIS 6.0)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296638%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- [How to Implement Kerberos Constrained Delegation with SQL Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg723715.aspx)

Comment: I'll check these out and see what I can come up with. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is some IIS setup required. See the following document for a good explanation:

[How to: Access SQL Server Using Windows Integrated Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx)

Comment: I've found this article, but it requires Basic Authentication. I don't feel that within the Microsoft circle of technologies (Active Directory, IIS, ASP.NET, SQL Server) that sending login information over the wire in plain text is a solution :(

Comment: @HardCode - I am using Integrated Windows authentication that doesn't send the credentials in clear text. The article mentions this. Your setup may vary.

Comment: Is your SQL Server on the same box as IIS? Mine are on separate boxes, hence the article's mention of Basic Authentication being the only means to pass the security token to SQL Server.

Comment: @HardCode - No, My IIS and SQL Server are on different boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change the way you are going to use AD in your app.

I would map AD users to app internal users together with their AD roles mapped to app roles and use app roles to determine access not to stored proc directly but to Business Layer functions

Comment: I do have Database Roles (not Application Roles) which the Active Directory groups map to, and those DB roles are mapped to the SPs. However, in the end, it still works out to allowing users in an AD group to access an SP.